# Edit .jsp file from Java - Tomcat websocket

Tags: java, jsp, web, tomcat, websocket

after much effort I managed to communicate a client with a tomcat server. I finally have the message in the server's `handleMessage`. I must now update the contents of the `index.jsp` file to add the message received.

This is my server java class:

```
package network.server;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/status")
public class WebSocket {
    private Set<Session> sessions = new HashSet<>();
    private Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println("Session opened in WebSocket ");
        this.session = session;
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message) {
        if (session.isOpen() && session != null){
            try {
                System.out.println("Received this message in the server: " + message);

                //TODO edit jsp
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("This is a totally unnecessary answer from the server.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Session is not opened or null");
        }
    }



    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Session closed ==>");
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The index.jsp is the default one:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello world!
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. To edit the jsp you must first `extends HttpServlet` in your java class and add the `@WebServlet("/uri")` on it. That makes it become a servlet and you can use the overridable functions of `doPost` and `doGet`.

Having done that, then in the jsp file, you can access those methods with the `method` tag such as this:

```
<form action="servlet" method="get" name="form">
    <input type="submit" value="View nodes"/>
  </form>
```

Where the action should match your `uri` used in the @WebServlet.

Either that or create an html of your own, associated to a javascript file that has a websocket in order to talk to Tomcat like this:

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/status");
socket.send("Hello there");
```

And answering from the tomcat with (s is session):

```
s.getBasicRemote().sendText("General kenobi");
```

Not using the jsp file that way, but you get to edit a website via that way too.

See a [servlet example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getattribute-passing-data-from-server-to-jsp/) here and a [websocket example](https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2017/02/23/websocket-con-java/) here.